# Mock a class method to throw an exception, so that I can test the exception scenario in a real method call

Tags: scala, mockito

Lets say I've a method `guardedRun` that runs a call method in a *Try* block. I want to test the exception handling in `guardedRun`

```
object Task {
  sealed trait TaskResponse

  case class TaskReport(returnCode: Int = 0,
                        exception: Option[Throwable] = None) extends TaskResponse
  ...
  ...
}

abstract class Task {
  def run(someVar: Map[String, Any]): Task.TaskResponse

  def guardedRun(retry: Boolean,
                 someVar: Map[String, Any]) : Task.TaskResponse = {
    Try(run(someVar)) match {
      case Success(response) => response
      case Failure(e) => e match {
        case SomeSpecificException(msg, cause) =>
            doStuffWithSomeSpecificException(msg, cause)
        case _ =>
            Task.TaskReport(exception = Some(e))
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I specifically want to test the scenario when `run` returns a non-SomeSpecificException.

Below is my attempt to do this using MockitoSugar
`org.scalatestplus" %% "mockito-3-4" % "3.2.7.0" % "test"`

```
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatestplus.mockito.MockitoSugar

class TaskTest extends AnyFlatSpec with MockitoSugar {

  val mockTaskReport = mock[Task]

  "guardedRun" should "return task report with exceptions in case task run throws exception" in {
     when(mockTaskReport.run(someVar = any[Map[String, Any]]()))
      .thenThrow(new Exception("something went wrong"))

    doCallRealMethod()
      .when(mockTaskReport)
      .guardedRun(false, Map[String, Any]())

    val response = mockTaskReport.guardedRun(retry = false, Map[String, Any]())

    assert(response.asInstanceOf[TaskReport].exception.isDefined)
    assertResult("something went wrong")(response.asInstanceOf[TaskReport].exception.get.getMessage)

  }

}
```

This however throws below exception from mockito
`Checked exception is invalid for this method! Invalid: java.lang.Exception: something went wrong`

One possible way is to throw Exception from `run` method, but I dont want to do that; plus it breaks the *Try* block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out `Exception` is a checked Exception, therefore the run method needs to throw `Exception` exception , since it's checked.

If I throw RunTimeException(which is unchecked) in my test case, its going to pass, which is what I want